# SwiftUI, handling user inputs

Tags: swiftui

I'm a SwiftUI beginner and have 0 knowledge on UIKIT or earlier versions of Swift programming.
I'm making a very simple IOS application using SwiftUI just for the practice.
Question is what am I supposed to use to handle user inputs and data?
I wanna make it like, if users put some inputs, those inputs will be saved and displayed, and any data shouldn't be deleted or updated until users delete or update.
Some people mention Core Data, Combine, Userdefaults and etc..
Can anyone give me an advice?

Comment: Pretty broad question. It would probably be a good step to check out some SwiftUI tutorials and start there -- they'll all handle user input in one way or another.

Comment: [SwiftUI Essentials Handling User Input](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input)

Comment: please specify the question what you need.
you may see [apples user input tutorial for swift ui here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input)

Comment: I've looked up the tutorial but in the tutorial, when you relaunch the app, whatever you marked as favorite, they just all gone and you get the reseted screen. To prevent from losing the user data, should I use Core Data?

Comment: Core Data and UserDefaults are two common options.

Answer (score 0):

Your difficulty appears to be SwiftUI, rather than the sort of backend data store you are using.

SwiftUI is confusing for beginners especially if you are used to imperative programming (conventional procedures and functions). It uses a Declarative programming approach instead.

If you understand the principles, you can easily get to grips with developing Apps using it, these are the essentials:

1. I have found the best way to think of it is " this isn't a program, it's a script that presents" - a bit like HTML. Think of it as a static page.
2. Now, this "static page"  changes its appearance based on some underlying data and rather than a program running to actively change the (e.g. color) appearance, the entire page gets reloaded! (it's called state). In the example below the whole page reloads with the new color when you tap on the text.
3. There's one last piece to this jigsaw - swift UI uses little bits of programming (called closures) to capture the user's input (e.g. a finger tap) and change the backend data (state) for example:

   ```
    @State var aColor: Color

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .foregroundColor(aColor)
            .onTapGesture {

                // A little bit of programming called a Closure

                if aColor == Color.red {
                    aColor = Color.green
                } else {
                    aColor = Color.red
                }
            }
    }
   ```

Note that in the above example I've used a local State variable. Is is usually more likely that the data you're working with will be held elsewhere in an "ObservableObject" and accessed by a line of code something like this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var myData: myDataClass
```

Which enables you to put the data manipulation stuff somewhere in its own class.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I kinda get what you're saying. And would you recommend any example code or templates of real apps that I can practice with? I've looked up github and saw like 20,30 codes of apps but none of them was really helpful cuz they just show me how to decode json file and don't really take User's input as an input. What I want to know is once I get User's input using textfield, where and how to store them properly and persistently...

Comment: Usually you would have an object (created in   @main App) created when the app starts. This is where you put data (and in turn that object saves the data to CoreData or somewhere else). Then you pass that object to the SwiftUI ContentView using .environmentObject modifier. You can then get and set values in the data object using the Closures I mentioned in the answer. For a editable textfield, there is a modifier called .onEditingChanged() {} - add the code there to save the textfield value back to your data object.

Comment: Just google for `@AppStorage`. There are plenty of sources (e.g. from Paul Hudsons [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper)). This is a convenient way to process data stored in `UserDefaults`. I would recommend you to go through 100 days of SwiftUI to learn the basics.